# Deactivate and activate Azure WebJobs in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment, azure-webjobs

i have a question, i want to deactivate webjobs of a appservice while deploying a new version and activate them after the deploying again.

is there a possibility in c# to do that?

thanky you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I known, you couldn't stop a triggered WebJob directly, you need to leverage process explorer to kill it via [KUDU](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Accessing-the-kudu-service). For the continuous WebJobs, you could leverage [WebJobs API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API) to start/stop the WebJobs, you need to invoke the specificed Rest API with basic auth using [Deployment credentials](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials) of your web app. Here is the c# code snippet to stop the WebJob:

```
string username = "{username}";
string password = "{password}";
string jobname = "{your-webjob-name}";
string authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}"));
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authorization);
    var res = await client.PostAsync($"https://{your-webapp-name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/continuouswebjobs/{jobname}/stop", null);
    Console.WriteLine($"StatusCode:{res.StatusCode}");
}
```

**Note:** At this point, a file named `disable.job` would be added with your WebJob as follows:

[image]

For start the WebJob, just call `/api/continuouswebjobs/{job name}/start`, then the `disable.job` file would be removed and your WebJob would run again.

Answer (score 2):

To stop the WebJob from an external client you just need to make a REST call: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#stop-a-continuous-job

```
 POST https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/continuouswebjobs/{job name}/stop
```

which will add a file of disabled.job

To start the WebJob again

```
   POST https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/continuouswebjobs/{job name}/start
```

which will remove disabled job file and webjob would run again

Comment: Good call (pun intended) on the web service to stop a WebJob. But what file are you referring to in order to start the WebJob again?