# How to disable a single WebJob under by WebApp?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webapps

I have a WebApp in Azure under which I have 10 WebJobs which runs in different schedules. Now based on business requirement, I need to stop the 2 jobs from running for next 2 weeks.

I heard that setting WEBJOBS_STOPPED = 1 in webapp appsettings, will stop all the webjobs. But I need to disable only 2 webjobs for only 2 weeks.

Is there any other Options?

I can do this by removing CRON expression from Settings.job. But I would like to know if there is any other approach in achieving this.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the above shared  information, we understood that you are trying to disable a specific triggered type webjobs.

- We don't have any [Rest API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#stop-a-continuous-job) or [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/webjob/triggered?view=azure-cli-latest) cmdlets to disable a triggered type web jobs.
- If you are using continuous webjobs you can disable a particular web job using either [Azure CLI cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/webjob/continuous?view=azure-cli-latest) or using  Rest API as mentioned in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271478/deactivate-and-activate-azure-webjobs-in-c-sharp)
  thread.